# Add retry inside an ajax call within a Promise

Tags: jquery, reactjs, ajax, asynchronous, promise

Need to implement a retry n times before rejecting an error on the following code:

```
const self = {

  fetchPreAuthnConfig: (data) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      $.ajax({
        url: preAuthnEndpoint,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: ({ configurations }) => {
          resolve(configurations);
        },
        error: (error) => {
          reject(error);
        },
      });
    });
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to do this.  In my opinion, all retries should contain some sort of delay before retrying to avoid avalanche failures (where one hiccup causes multiple clients to immediately try to hammer the target server).  And, you should have a max number of times you retry.

Here's one way to implement that:

```
function delay(t) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, t);
    });
}

const retryDelay = 500;
const retryMax = 5;

const self = {

  fetchPreAuthnConfig: (data) => {
      let retryCntr = 0;
      function run() {
          return $.ajax({
            url: preAuthnEndpoint,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
        }).then(({configurations}) => {
            return configurations;
        }).catch(err => {
            ++retryCntr;
            if (retryCntr < retryMax) {
                // retry after a delay
                return delay(retryDelay).then(run);
            } else {
                throw err;
            }
        });
    }
    return run();
  }
};
```

Ideally, you would also know your endpoint and only retry certain types of errors (or not retry certain types of errors) as some types of errors are likely permanent and retrying those only wastes resources and delays the inevitable.

Comment: Is there a way to implement async-retry library for this? The above code is kinda breaking the original functionality.

Comment: @AksheyPradhan - How does this break the original functionality?  It returns a promise that resolves or rejects the same as your original code.  It just retries before rejecting which is what I thought you were asking for.  And, it uses the built-in promise capabilities in `$.ajax()` rather than wrapping it in another promise.

Comment: @AksheyPradhan - What does this not do that you asked for?

Comment: So this `const self` is being imported in another file, that is causing the problem. Fixed it by using **async-retry** library in the said file itself. Although the above jquery needs to be written as a fetch call. Thanks @jfriend00

Comment: @Genesis - `const self` is just copied from your question.  That's the structure you were using so I have no idea what any of that is about.  I showed you a retry solution that works which is what your question asked for.  Not sure what else you want.  In the future if you want a solution using a particular library, then try to implement that yourself and if you get stuck post a question about implementing with that particular library and show your code using that library and explain where you got stuck.  Your question says NOTHING about the `async-retry` library.